# In AWS cloudwatch I am trying to give access to only one specific log group but its showing all the log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am creating a read and list IAM policy to access only one log group. This is the policy I am using for a specific log group but its showing all the log groups on AWS console.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you show your policy? Typically list calls can not be scoped to a single resource.

Answer (score 1):

List permissions mean you are allowing user to list all log groups. If you need to give permission to view only 1 log group and also not show names of all other log groups, then do not give list permission. Instead give the read permission for that one log group and give the person direct url for accessing the log group.